# Excel Macro to find/replace in Sheets & VBA Modules

Tags: excel

I am looking to write a macro to have in my Personal Macro Workbook that will be able to be activated and run a series of Find/Replace's both on the worksheets of any Spreadsheet I have open and within the VBA of any macros inside that spreadsheet. The worksheets part of this is easy, but I cannot find a way to do it to the Visual Basic Editor, and trying to record the macro seems to not pick up anything done in VBA. I do not care if the code is clever enough to go through every VBA module or it needs to go "module1", "module2" and so on and run the find/replaces for each module seperately (because I guarantee that none of them are named otherwise); but so far, I have not been able to find anything that works and does an automatic find/replace in Excel VBA.

If it helps as an example, I am looking to change any reference in the VBA of "" to "/"

Thanks

I have found something online about using VBINDE to change constants; but I haven't been able to modify it to change text as above.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far. It`s also no clear what the exact problem you are facing is

Comment: I dont think the code I have so far is worth sharing to be honest as its not even close to doing what I need and its not coming up with any errors, its just not replacing anything so I dont think its working at all. So I am looking for a fresh start really if someone knows the vba code to find/replace in vba rather than worksheets

Comment: If your code was working, then you wouldn't be here to begin with.... this is not a free code writing service, but we're happy to look at existing code and help with it